# Check if time is the same with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

How to check if time is the same for Moment objects with different dates?

For example I have object like

```
const endDate = moment().add(30, 'days').endOf('day');
```

and I want to check if some moment object is `endOf` day.

```
private isEndOfDay(dateTime: string) {
    const m = moment().endOf('day');

    return m.isSame(dateTime, 'minute');
}

const receivedDateFormat: string = 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss';

this.isEndOfDay(this.endDate.format(this.receivedDateFormat))
```

But for this case, when I pass "minute" parameter, it will check minute, hour, day, month and year... which isn't what I want to check.

Comment: `dateTime` is a string, you need to convert it to a moment

Comment: @Satpal, yes, it is a string... But according to this page, I can pass string http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/

Comment: Which is the value of `dateTime`? The string must be parsable by moment (e.g. ISO 8601 format)

Comment: @VincenzoC, I've update example... I convert `endDate` to string in some defined format... Then this endDate string pass to function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part of the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) that explains that behaviour is

> When including a second parameter, it will match all units equal or larger. Passing in month will check month and year. Passing in day will check day, month, and year.

So, if you just want to compare the minutes, you'll need to do something like

```
endDate.minute() === startDate.minute()
```

To compare the time only, format() the dates

```
endDate.format('HH:mm:ss') === startDate.format('HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: In case to check not only minutes, but all time (hours, minutes, seconds...) ?

Comment: Updated the answer @demo

Comment: This condition will give true when comparing `11:00:00` and `23:00:00`, use uppercase `HH` to get 24 hours format.

Comment: Thanks @VincenzoC

Comment: what is endDate is it from moment.js ?

Answer (score 1):

To compare only time part you can set a given date (year, month and day) to your input.

Please note that passing `'minute'` to [`isSame`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) will ignore seconds.

Here a live sample:

```js
function isEndOfDay(dateTime) {
  let m = moment().endOf('day');
  let m2 = moment(dateTime);
  m2.set({
    y: m.year(),
    M: m.month(),
    D: m.date()
  });
  return m.isSame(m2, 'minute');
}

var endDate = moment().add(30, 'days').endOf('day');
const receivedDateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss';

var ret = isEndOfDay(endDate.format(this.receivedDateFormat))
console.log(ret);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Another way to to is checking only units that matter for you:

```js
function isEndOfDay(dateTime) {
  let m = moment().endOf('day');
  let m2 = moment(dateTime);
  if( m.hours() === m2.hours() &&
      m.minutes() === m2.minutes() &&
      m.seconds() === m2.seconds() ){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

var endDate = moment().add(30, 'days').endOf('day');
const receivedDateFormat = 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss';

var ret = isEndOfDay(endDate.format(this.receivedDateFormat))
console.log(ret);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

See [Get + Set](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/) section of the docs to see how to get and set units of moment objects.